# Jackson, how do I apply a mixin to map representing another object?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

so I have an `object Foo`, with mixin `FooMixin` that is applied appropriately when it passes through the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

However, I now have another object `FooMap` (Simple HashMap) which is identical to Foo in terms of properties, except not all the attributes exist.

How might I be able to apply the same FooMixin to this `Map` object?

Comment: Use a different mixin.

Comment: Okay, so how do I apply a Mixin to an object that extends HashMap?

Comment: Don't do that. Use composition. Have you POJO include a field for the `HashMap`. Then the mixin is just like for any other POJO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I wanted to reuse an existing Mixin. I ended up going with another bean similar to Foo and reusing FooMixin.